# Jquery menu close after click on link

Tags: jquery

I'm using http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/responsive-web-nav/ this tutorial exactly for my site menu, but the only problem is I am making a one page website. I want the mobile menu to close after I click on 'about' for example. so that it will scroll to the bottom.

I hope you can help me.

This is my cod:

```
     <!-- Menu Navigation Start -->
    <nav class="clearfix">  
        <ul class="clearfix">  
            <li><a href="#">k</a></li>  
            <li><a href="#">How-to</a></li>  
            <li><a href="#">Icons</a></li>  
            <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>  
            <li><a href="#">Web 2.0</a></li>  
            <li><a href="#">Tools</a></li>    
        </ul>  
                <a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>  
    </nav>
```

And this is the javascript:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var pull        = $('#pull');
            menu        = $('nav ul');
            menuHeight  = menu.height();

        $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            menu.slideToggle();
        });

        $(window).resize(function(){
            var w = $(window).width();
            if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
                menu.removeAttr('style');
            }
        });


    });



</script>
```

Comment: can you post your code

Answer (score 0):

The selecor is wrong

if you have

```
var pull        = $('#pull');
```

Wouldn't it be

```
    pull.on('click', function(e) {...
```

or just

```
$('#pull').on(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It'll execute the slideToggle function when a nav item is clicked.

```
menu.find('a').click(function(){
    menu.slideToggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want slideUp the Menu when you click outside of it you can use the method

```
stopPropagation();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Joseph82/jwNEZ/

Comment: Thank you but, i have another problem. if i have the menu at desktop size, if i click somewehre on the page the menu dissapears